# Why function returns boolean value?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am writing my own function which returns lower argument between two arguments.

My first solution was:

```
function min(a, b) {
  if (a < b)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}

console.log(min(0, 10));
// → 0
```

But I wanted to simplify it and wrote another one function:

```
function min(a, b) {
   return a ? a < b : b;
}
console.log(min(0, 10));
// → true
```

Why my second function returns boolean value instead of number? Can I change this behavior?

Comment: `a ? a < b : b` what does this expression mean?

Comment: `Can I change this behavior?` - what you need to change is your understanding of how `condition ? whentruthy : whenfalsey` works :p

Comment: If *a* is 0 then it's falsey so `a? a < b : b` should return *b* (i.e. 10), not *true*.

Comment: @zerkms exactly right. I didn't pay attention. Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
function min(a, b) {
   return a < b ? a : b;
}
console.log(min(0, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ternary operater is a little funky.

It should be `boolean ? returnValueForTrue : returnValueForFalse;`

So yours is doing `a ? boolean : b` and I'm not sure what that actually turns into.  `a ? boolean` would turn into a boolean.

So yours should be

`return a < b ? a : b;`